# Почему у меня не получается установить LeakCanary в моё Android-приложение?

Tags: android, утечка-памяти

Добавляю строчку `LeakCanary.install(this);` в `onCreate`. Пишет Cannot resolve symbol 'install' in 'LeakCanary'.

Comment: Потому что для использования не требуется инициализации - только добавить зависимость

Comment: А как LeakCanary оповещает об утечках? Уведомления не приходят никакие.

Comment: Давно не использовал - не помню, кажется там активити есть специальная, либо настраивать что-то нужно. Вот вам доки, изучайте: https://square.github.io/leakcanary/

Comment: вверху появляется нотификация с логотипом. нажимаешь на нее, начинается сбор подробной инфы и потом можно посмотреть полный отчет утечки. а чтобы проверить, работает ли ЛикКанари, загляни в логи. должно быть сообщение `D LeakCanary: LeakCanary is running and ready to detect leaks`

Comment: ```D/LeakCanary: Check for retained object found no objects remaining``` - это типа нет утечек?